# Why can't we swap conflicting operations of a schedule?

Tags: database, transactions, rdbms

- T1: | W(X) |------| R(X) |
- T2: |------| R(X) |------|

X represents a database object, W represents write operation and R represents read operation.

What will be the consequences of swapping confliction actions W(X) of T1 and R(X) of T2?

Comment: "Why" & "consequences" are way too vague. Also, your title & body ask different questions. What is your 1 clear specific (researched non-duplicate) question? Where are you stuck in answering it yourself & what are you able to do towards answering? [ask] [help]

Answer (score -1):

Swapping conflicting operations gives you a schedule, representing different serial order of transactions. Your example corresponds to a serial order T1, T2. After swapping it will be T2, T1, giving completely different outcome.